# Parametric form of curves?

Tags: parametric

Can someone tell me the steps to get the parametric form of a curve?
For example:

$x^{2\over 3}$ +$y^{2\over 3}$ =1

Comment: You could substitute $y = tx$ into the equation of the curve and solve it for $x$ in terms of $t$, then obtain an expression for $y$ from the relation $y=tx$.

Comment: i will try it,thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How would you parametrize $x^2 + y^2 = 1$? Recall the well-known identity $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$, and the obvious parametrization is $x = \cos \theta$, $y = \sin \theta$. Can you think of something similar here?

The same parametrization doesn't work, because of the cube roots. Somehow you need to make the cube roots go away and get $\cos^2 \theta$ and $\sin^2 \theta$. Think and try to get it on your own, otherwise read further.

As you want $x^{2/3}$ to be $\cos^2 \theta$, obviously, put $x = \cos^3 \theta$. Similarly, $y = \sin^3 \theta$.

More generally, for the astroid $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = a^{2/3}$, the parametrization is $x = a\cos^3 \theta$, $y = a\sin^3 \theta$.